# Why did Yusuf own both a Rosary and a Koran?

Tags: abdulrazak-gurnah, paradise

When Yusuf left with his Uncle Aziz, some of the items he brought included a copy of the Koran and his mother's old rosary. Why would he have had both?

Comment: Can you explain why his having both is puzzling?

Comment: @verbose That term is usually associated with Roman Catholicism, not Islam.

Comment: They are usually called "prayer beads" rather than a rosary, but Muslims definitely use them, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prayer_beads

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez So this is just the author using an unusual term?

Comment: You can see a photo of both objects [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/98/Qur%27an_and_tespih.jpg).

Comment: It's usually called [misbaha](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/misbaha).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Very little information is given about Yusuf's mother, in fact, I do not think we even learn her name. One of the few things that we do know is that "she was the daughter of a hill tribesman from the back of Taita" - a phrase that her husband used to fling at her in arguments. Taita is a remote region in present day Kenya, and its inhabitants (according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taita_people)) "are mostly muslims with a few Christians towards the western side of the county."

But whether she was Christian or Muslim does not really matter much, as both religions make use of beads on strings to count prayers. Although it is more normal for Roman Catholics to use the word "rosary" it is not uncommon for Muslims to use this term too. Indeed Gurnah uses the term "rosary" later in the book to describe Islamic prayer beads:

> Yusuf went to the mosque every day, and submitted and humbled himself
> to the God he had neglected for so long. The imam sent him on small
> errands in front of the other worshippers, a token of his trust and
> approbation. He sent him to fetch a book from which he intended to
> read to his congregation, or to fetch the **rosary** or the incense
> burner.

Gurnah also describes rich merchants (*seyyid*) as carrying "moneybags across your belly and a rosary round your wrist". So it seems that Gurnah uses the word "rosary" to describe Islamic prayer beads. Whether the rosary given to Yusuf by his mother is a sentimental keepsake of her own (possible) Catholicism, or is a functional item of Muslim devotion, is not spelled out. But given that so little is said about his mother's beliefs, the second explanation is probably the most economical.